# Why the skipPreamble() return false?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

I am using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/ to parse multipart form and extract an uploaded file. I am following this manual http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2006/06/parsing_formdata_multiparts.html and fresh new documentation from inside that package. The request.getContentLength() is saying 700K and that is the code

```
InputStream input = request.getInputStream();
MultipartStream mStream = new MultipartStream(input, boundArray, 94096 /*random number*/, null);
boolean part = mStream.skipPreamble();
```

And the part is always **false**. Could anybody tell me why?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to code of [MultipartStream.java](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3&path=/Source%20Packages/org.apache.commons.fileupload/MultipartStream.java&line=616) you get MalformedStreamException in discardBodyData or readBoundary.

Looks like discardBodyData only declares that, bun never throws MalformedStreamException.

readBoundary throws MalformedStreamException("Unexpected characters follow a boundary") and  MalformedStreamException("Stream ended unexpectedly").

Comment says:

```
* @throws MalformedStreamException if the stream ends unexpectedly or
*                                  fails to follow required syntax
```

Hypothesis:
**94096 /*random number*/** is supposed to be buffer size.
94096 is not enough for 700K, so for MultipartStream stream ends unexpectedly.

Comment: No, the problem is same for new MultipartStream(input, boundArray, request.getContentLength(), null);

Comment: Could you provide more details about boundArray then. Do you create the same way as article says? What is value you get?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your cooperation, but this is not an issue any more. I have found new User Guide here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html and it works.